# Mysql объединение 4-х таблиц в 1 запросе

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli

**Есть 4 таблицы:**

1. `rent` содержит поля (`id`, `mark` - цифра, `model` - цифра, `year`, `run`, `price`, `description`,`rent_photo`)
2. `mark` содержит поля (id, title - название марок, например Audi)
3. `model` cодержит поля (id, title - название моделей, например А8, mark_id - содержит цифру для присоединения с таблицей `mark`)
4. `rent_photo` в данном случае имеет поля (`id`, `rent_id`. `photo` - ссылка на изображения)

Задача вывести данные по каждому `ID` для объявлений.

Запрос ниже выводит нужные данные, но не показывает марку и модель соответственно потому-что непонятно как это включить в команду.

```
SELECT 
                    rent.id, 
                    rent.year, 
                    rent.run, 
                    rent.price, 
                    rent.description,
                    rent_photo.photo AS img
            FROM 
                    rent
            LEFT JOIN
                    rent_photo
            ON
                    rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id 
            WHERE 
                    rent.id IN (8624, 8625, 8626) 
            ORDER BY 
                    rent.time_upload DESC
```

В PHP данные выводятся так. Нужную строку выделил пробелом сверху и снизу.

```
<?php if (isset($top3)): ?>  
<div class="main">  
<div class="row">  
<?php foreach($top3 as $id => $ads): ?>
  <a href="ads/rent/<?=$id;?>">
  <div class="column">
     <div class="content">
       


<h3><?php isset($ads['mark']) ? $ads['model'] : null; ?></h3>     
       



<h3><?=$ads['year']; ?></h3>
               <?php if(isset($ads['img'])): ?>
                         <img src="Download_Rent/<?=$ads['img'];?>" width="100%">
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                             <img src="Photo/No photo.jpg" width="100%">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
           <h3>Цена:  <?= number_format($ads['price'], 0, '.', '.'); ?> Р.</h3>
      <?php if (isset($ads['run'])):?>      
            <h3>Пробег: <?=number_format($ads['run'], 0, '.', ' '); ?>   км.</h3>
      <?php endif; ?> 
         <p><?=substr($ads['description'], 0, 120),'...'; ?></p>
                <button class="PreviewADS">Подробнее...</button>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>      
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Вопрос:**

Как правильно объединить этот запрос в 1 команду Mysql?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то используйте также join'ы для остальных таблиц, а в операторе select выводите также нужные поля данных таблиц (mark.title, и т.д.)

Comment: @Kirill Babinec   Буду крайне благодарен коду, в Sql пока не силен.

Comment: несколько inner join у вас будет да и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  rent.id, 
  rent.year, 
  rent.run, 
  rent.price, 
  rent.description,
  rent_photo.photo AS img,
  mark.title AS mark,
  model.title AS model
FROM rent
INNER JOIN mark ON rent.mark = mark.id
INNER JOIN model ON rent.model = model.id
LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
WHERE rent.id IN (8624, 8625, 8626) 
ORDER BY rent.time_upload DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Здоровья и успехов!